# Multiple sources in one link HTML

Tags: html

I have a link in html:

```
<a id="clicky" href="http://localhost:8080/filesystem/IT.xls"><p>Download</p></a>
```

to which I would like to add additional .xls files for download. Is there a way to give a link multiple sources or to combine the sheets on the user end?

Comment: Not really... You could fire multiple JavaScript `location.href`'s, not sure whether that'll work tho

Comment: Not really. You could zip multiple ones up, and offer the zip, or link to a page with a list of all the xls files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A link can only point at a single URL (aka resource). Nothing says that resource can't return multiple things, e.g. all the requested files in a .zip, e.g.

```
http://example.com?file1=one.xls&file2=two.xls&file3=three.xls
```

Comment: so if I would normally pull one file from "http://localhost:8080/filesystem/IT.xls", would it be "http://localhost:8080/filesystem?file1=IT.xls&file2=IT2.xls&file3=IT3.xls"

Comment: and does that automatically zip the files together?

Comment: no. that's just a url. you'd have to write a script to do that. which is way beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: So what does the URL do? I've tried to call a similar URL (I may have gotten the syntax wrong), but it returns a lost page

Comment: urls don't do anything. you need to build a script on your server that you point at and pass in any number of files to be zipped up.

Comment: Ok, well I was hoping to do this without a script, but if it's not possible I'll see what I can manage. Thanks for your help.